# Apache storm nimbus run error, supervisor , ui issue. Windows

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I have installed storm and ZooKeeper by following the instructions on  tutorialspoint website but I have an issue while running nimbus, supervisor, ui. link for error picture [image01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkGaX.png). My zookeeper is running properly but facing 'couldn't load main class Files\java\jdk....' in storm. my storm.yaml file is something like [storm.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En5Kt.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. It is caused by space in Java_Home path. Please set your JAVA_HOME to path which does not have space.

This solution resolved this error for me.